# Converting a String to Set<String>

Tags: java

Sorry for the basic question but I have a Java `String` that I need to return as part of a method as a `Set<String>`

I cannot find a reference on how to do this.  Any clues?

Comment: You mean you need to return a `Set` containing one single `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Java 9 or newer, use [`Set.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E)):

```
return Set.of("foo");
```

Answer (score 6):

The usual way to do this, with a normal set:

```
String s = "hello";
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(s)
return set;
```

Or if you prefer an immutable set with just a single element:

```
String s = "hello";
return Collections.singleton(s);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Collections.singleton("yourString")
```